# iOSのApp Extension を利用したキーボードの高さが調整できない。

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

iOSのApp Extension を利用したキーボード（カスタムキーボード）で高さを調整しようと思い下記のコードを`viewDidAppear`と`updateViewConstraints`に追加したのですが高さが変わりません。
解決方法をご存知の方、教えて下さい。

このコードは[Appleのドキュメント](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard/Keyboard.html)を参考にしました。

```
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: nil,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 0.0,
        constant: 400)
self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

環境
Xcode7.2
iOS9,8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

私は以下の方法で、設定しています。

```
//前もって高さを設定
pHeight=400

//以下の関数をオーバーライド
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //以下で高さ変更
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0,constant: pHeight)
    view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
}
```

参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 一応試したのですがやはり同じです

Comment: このコードとあなたのコードの主な違いですが、selfの有る無しだと思いますが、いかがでしょうか？それを変えてもだめでしょうか？

Comment: selfの有無も試しましたが結果は同じです

Comment: ここの検索機能で「キーボードの高さ」で検索してみてください。昨年の８月に同じ質問があります。私はこれで解決しました。

Comment: 一度適当にプロジェクトを作って試したところ上手く行きました。
既存のコードの問題点を探してみます。ありがとうございました。